# cURL not getting response from server?

Tags: php, curl, dedicated-server

I am trying to use cURL to get a response from a different server after it executes a SSH command. When doing so, I thought it was a connection error because I was not receiving any response from the server. So I made a test file and it outputs "Works!", but cURL is not picking up ANYTHING from it. It puts my page into a waiting loop then just quits and has no response back.

test.php Code:

```
<?php echo "works!"; ?>
```

Now the code that tries to get the "Works!" response.

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://SERVERIP/test/test.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

Also, if it help, I recently just upgraded to a CDN Server. Contacted them and they said it's more than likely a software problem. So I figured I'd ask you all!

Any reply on help will be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried to call `curl_error()` and/or `curl_getinfo()` to evaluate what is happening with the response?

Comment: What do you see when you issue a `wget http://SERVERIP/test/test.php` from the same server where your curl script is ? do you have any `.htaccess rules` in place ?

Comment: is the test file called `Test.php` or `test.php` ?

Comment: It's test.php with a lowercase t. Let me edit it and adjust the header. But I do not have any .htaccess rules in to my knowledge as I have not changed them over the past two days and it was working 3 days ago. I'll try the options you gave me Mike and I'll post back with it. And let me try to do the wget. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Tried the wget and it worked. The file's in place and get's downloaded. As for the curl_error() and curl_getinfo():

For curl_getinfo() it originally told me that it needs a parameter so I added the $ch (see it above in the OP), and it gave me this back

Warning: curl_getinfo(): 10 is not a valid cURL handle resource

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`

**ex:**

```
<?php
//I've added this two lines for debug, run the script and check for errors, when done, comment the lines.  
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1)

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://SERVERIP/test/test.php"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
?>
```

Based on your comments, I've updated the answer:

**To Turn Off PHP Safe Mode on Your Linux Server**

> ```
> Using SSH, connect to your server.
> Once you are logged in, type su - root.
> For your password, type the same password you used to connect to your server.
> At the command prompt type:
> vi /etc/php.ini
> Go to the line safe_mode = on and press the "i" key.
> Change the line to safe_mode = off and press the "Esc" key.
> Type :wq! to save your file.
> ```

**To Turn Off PHP Safe Mode on Your Windows Server**

```
Using Remote Desktop Connection, log in to your server as an administrator.  
Open c:\windowsphp.ini in Notepad.  
Change the line safe_mode = on to safe_mode = off.  
Save and close php.ini.
```

**Enabling curl on php.ini:**

**Windows:**

Locate php.ini and uncomment:

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

**Linux:**
On debian with apache2:

```
apt-get install php5-curl
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

(php4-curl if it's php4)

Make sure your php was compiled with curl support, make a script with the following code:

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

search for CURL there.

Comment: Nope. It's still in a loading loop. And it's giving me this "Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set {URL}"

Comment: Had the company I am hosting my web server with turn it back on. They must've disabled it the other day. Anyways, thanks for helping!